# Retrieving buyer/payer email in from PayPal Digital Goods Express Checkout

Tags: email, paypal, express-checkout, paypal-digital-goods

I am new to PHP scripting, as well as to PayPal's Digital Goods Express Checkout.  I integrated into the orderconfirm.php file code that would automatically generate an email with additional information for the buyer.  The one problem I seem to be having, and I've searched all over trying to find a solution, is that I can't seem to figure out the proper syntax and coding for retrieving the buyer/payer's email address to include in that portion of the script.  I notice that depending on where you look PayPal has a different name for the buyer's email address, (ie, payer, email, payeremail, etc.).  Can anyone tell me, and give me an example I can work with, the proper coding and syntax for accomplishing this?  I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You can do a GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call or use Instant Payment Notification (IPN).

With GetExpressCheckoutDetails you'll look up the Express Checkout token and receive a bunch of information on the buyer including their e-mail address. The token does expire after 3 hours so if you're after the information later that may not work for you.

IPN sends out a post to a notification URL you set including information on the payment and buyer (with their e-mail address).